# Asymptotic Behavior of a function around infinity

Tags: series-expansion

I would like to find how 
`(E^(-(λ/μ)) (λ/μ)^k Gamma[1 + k])/(k! Gamma[1 + k, λ/μ])` behaves as Lambda->Infinity

I used the following Mathematica function:

```
Normal[Series[(E^(-(λ/μ)) (λ/μ)^k Gamma[1 + k])/(k! Gamma[1 + k, λ/μ]), {λ, Infinity, 1}]]
```

I am simply not sure what should the order be in `{λ, Infinity, 1}`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A trick in this case is to replace `λ` by `1/x`, expand around `x=0`, and change back to `λ`:

```
Normal[Series[
    (E^(-(λ/μ)) (λ/μ)^k Gamma[1 + k])/(k! Gamma[1 + k, λ/]) /. λ -> 1/x, {x, 0, 1},
    Assumptions -> {x > 0, μ > 0, k > 0}
  ]] /.x -> 1/λ
(* (λ/μ)^k (μ/λ)^k (Gamma[1 + k]/k! - (k μ Gamma[1 + k])/(λ k!)) *)
```

Result in TeX:

$\left(\frac{\lambda }{\mu }\right)^k \left(\frac{\mu }{\lambda }\right)^k \left(\frac{\Gamma (k+1)}{k!}-\frac{k \mu  \Gamma
   (k+1)}{\lambda  k!}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your only issue is that the result isn't sufficiently simplified. So how about this:

```
Assuming[{λ > 0}, 
Simplify[Normal[
 Series[(E^(-(λ/μ)) (λ/μ)^k Gamma[1 + k])/(k! Gamma[1 + k, λ/μ]), {λ, Infinity, 1}]
 ]
]]
```

> $$\frac{\Gamma (k+1) (\lambda -k \mu )}{\lambda  k!}$$

The *order* in your `Series` is `1`, and that's why you have a term proportional to $1/\lambda$. If you change the order from `1` to `0`, only the leading term in $\lambda$ will be returned, which is a constant.

You can separate the orders by doing `Expand[%]` or `Collect[%, λ]`

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to find out how the function behaves as lamda -> Infinity, why not take the Limit?

```
Limit[(E^(-(λ/μ)) (λ/μ)^k Gamma[
 1 + k])/(k! Gamma[1 + k, λ/μ]), λ -> Infinity]

Gamma[1 + k]/k!
```